# CakePHP model caching function name

Tags: php, cakephp

Im quite familiar with CakePHP 2.0 but this is something I haven't seen yet.

My Model is trying to run function that doesn't exist in itself. This only happens in Linux environment and I double checked that filenames are correct. I had before situation with filenames didn't match. In Windows environment code works just good.

Background for this. I had early functions named like "sql_version_xx" and they just worked well until today, version 33 started fail. All functions below 33 worked like charm. 33 and all above dies with this mysterious error. I guess this is some stupid typo but I really cant find it out. Error is still same even I renamed functions (I thought it had something to do CakePHP style to convert SqlVersion33 to sql_version_33 and vice versa). Renaming didn't help.

Code is built for managing software database updates which we have a lot at this stage :D

Could someone catch the typo here?

Here are details for case:

- Model is name Installer.php
- Controller is InstallersController.php

Here is the error:

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sql_version_33' at line 1

SQL Query: sql_version_33

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/pdo_error.ctp

Stack Trace
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 460 → PDOStatement->execute(array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 426 → DboSource->_execute(string, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 666 → DboSource->execute(string, array, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 611 → DboSource->fetchAll(string, array, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 799 → DboSource->query(string, array, Installer)
APP/Model/Installer.php line 16 → Model->__call(string, array)
APP/Model/Installer.php line 16 → Installer->sql_version_33()
APP/Controller/InstallersController.php line 35 → Installer->Install(string)
[internal function] → InstallersController->install(string)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(InstallersController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 187 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(InstallersController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 92 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Here is code snippet from model:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::import('Model', 'CContact');

class Installer extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'c_event';
    private $sql = array();
    private $sql_indexes = array();
    private $messages = array();


public function Install($version){
    $this->sql = array();
    $sql_function = 'sqlversion' . $version;
    if(method_exists('Installer', $sql_function)) $this->$sql_function();
    $string = '';

    foreach($this->sql as $sql)
        $string .= $sql . ';';

    $dataSource = $this->getDataSource();
    $dataSource->begin();
    try{
        if(strlen($string)>0)
            $this->SqlQuery($string);
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $dataSource->rollback();
        return array('exception' => $e->getMessage(), 'sql' => $this->sql);
    }
    $dataSource->commit();
}
```

And here is couple of functions from same model:

```
public function sqlversion34(){
    if(!array_key_exists('delay', $this->desc_table('k4_drafts')))
        $this->sql[] = "ALTER TABLE k4_drafts ADD delay DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL";
    if(!array_key_exists('remark', $this->desc_table('k4_drafts')))
        $this->sql[] = "ALTER TABLE k4_drafts ADD remark DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL";
    if(!array_key_exists('payday', $this->desc_table('k4_drafts')))
        $this->sql[] = "ALTER TABLE k4_drafts ADD payday DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL";
    }

    public function sqlversion33(){
        if(array_key_exists('payday', $this->desc_table('k4_drafts')))
            $this->sql[] = "ALTER TABLE k4_drafts DROP payday";
    }

    public function sqlversion32(){
        $this->sql[] = "ALTER TABLE k4_row_pen_intr CHANGE create_stamp create_stamp TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP";
    }
```

As you can see. There is no function calls to function "sql_version_33" and still I get this error message.

**EDIT: Problem solved**

Comment: Ok. This far I found that problem is totally somewhere else. If comment out all model method calls from controller I still get same error. Problem is somewhere else but I still wonder how the the hell code can "know" to call function named "sql_version_33" when I dont have any function calls at all :D

Comment: Ok. This problem was totally strange. It had something to do with server which wasn't working correctly. After reboot everything works like a charm. Really strange part here was, that files for apache server was totally coming somewhere else than casual www-root directory. I updated files but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, your problem is here:

APP/Model/Installer.php line 16 → Installer->sql_version_33()

Have a look on line 16 of /App/Model/Installer to see what that call is.  Perhaps try changing that to sqlversion33().

Comment: Yes its true. But model doesnt contain such function. Problem is somewhere else cause all methods in InstallersContoller fails to run.

Comment: Post the first 30 lines of /APP/Model/Installer.php

Comment: You've either not uploaded Installer.php, or you've posted a different version to what's running on your website.  Try putting a die("This is the right version"); on line 15.

Comment: I went to server bash and looked for file. It is correct. Thats why title has mention of caching. Server has 100% right files in it but contet is coming from some cache.